# How to concatenate transformations on a spark scala dataframe?

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I am teaching myself scala (so as to use it with Apache Spark) and wanted to know if there would be some way to concatenate a series of transformations on a Spark DataFrame. E.g. let's assume we have a list of transformations

`l: List[(String, String)] = List(("field1", "nonEmpty"), ("field2", "notNull"))`

and a Spark DataFrame

`df`, such that the desired result would be

`df.filter(df("field1") =!= "").filter(df("field2").isNotNull)`.

I was thinking perhaps this could be done using function composition or list folding or something, but I really don't know how. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is perfectly possible. But it depends of you really want, I mean, Spark provides [Pipelines](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/ml-pipeline.html), that allows to compose your transformations and  create a pipeline that can be serialized. You can create your custom transformers, [here](https://qikaigu.com/serializable-custom-transformer-with-spark-2/) an example. You can include your "filter" stages in custom transformations, you will be able to use later, for example,  in a Spark structured streaming.

Other option is to use Spark datasets and use the [transform](https://kb.databricks.com/data/chained-transformations.html#functionchain-api) api. That seems more functional and elegant.

Scala has a lot of possibilities to create your own api, but take a look first to these approaches.

Comment: Wow, I did not know about spark Pipelines nor the Transform API. Thanks very much for your answer!

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can fold over an existing `Dataframe`. You could keep all columns in a list and don't bother with other intermediary types:

```scala
val df =
 ???

val columns =
  List(
    col("1") =!= "",
    col("2").isNotNull,
    col("3") > 10
 )
  
val filtered = 
  columns.foldLeft(df)((df, col) => df.filter(col))
```